# Editing the P of a List Item

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if I had something like this, would it work?

```
#DivBlaBla li p {
}
```

Would that change the text on that li? If not what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

It will  change the paragragh content within the div #divblabla
Because p is a child of div #divblabla

Answer (score 0):

I think do you mean yo want to change a paragrph

wich is inside of a .

You must know that the html tags have two attributes id or class. If you write a sentence like:

```
<div id="DivBlaBla"></div>
```

You are setting up the id attribute and only one element of the html page could have it. On the other hand if you write:

```
<div class="DivBlaBla"></div>
```

Now you're setting up the class attribute and you can use it as many times as you want.

To refer to the id in your CSS you use the "#" and if you want to refer to a class you use ".".

So in your example you're refering to a div with a id="DivBlaBla", and then you are calling to all the p elements inside the div. You have to write the p in lowercase, because css and html are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

It will only change the style of every `<p>` inside every `<li>` inside `#DivBlaBla`, no matter how many levels.

In the next example Y is where the style will be applied, X where it will still unchanged:

```
<div id=#DivBlaBla>
   <ul>
     <li>XXXXX<p>YYYYYY</p>XXXX</li>
     <li>XXXXX/li>
     <li><p>YYYYYY</p></li>
   </ul>
   <div id=Divception>
      <ul>
          <li>XX<p>YYYYY</p></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div id=#DivBla2>
   <ul>
     <li>XXXXX<p>XXX</p>XXXX</li>
     <li>XXXXX/li>
     <li><p>XXXX</p></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here you have a selector list: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Would that change the text on that li? If not what would it be?

No. Only any `<p>` tags inside `<li>` tags inside `<div id="DivBlaBla">` will be affected by the CSS. `<li>` text will be unaffected.

```css
#DivBlaBla li p {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="DivBlaBla">This is my DIV text.
  <li>This is my LI text
  <p>Only my P text is red</p>
  </li>
  <li>This is more LI text
  <p>More P text is red</p>
  </li>
</div>
```